# C++ Candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'char [4]')

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code that fails when I call a `bfs` function and pass `string` literal as an argument:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using Graph = unordered_map<T, vector<T> >;

template<typename T>
vector<T> bfs(const Graph<T>& graph, const T& root) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    Graph<string> social_network = {
        {"you", {"tony", "steve", "nick"}},
        {"tony", {"clint"}},
        {"nick", {"thor", "natasha"}},
        {"steve", {"phil", "clint"}}
    };

    bfs(social_network, "you"); <-- the problem is here
}
```

The error is the following:

```
Candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'char [4]')
```

if I explicitly specify `string` type for the argument, the code compiles successfully:

```cpp
bfs(social_network, string("you"));
```

Is there a way to pass a `string` literal as an argument and make this code compile as well:

```cpp
bfs(social_network, "you");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make type of root as *being ignored* in deduction of template parameters by using `type_identity_t` (required c++20), then `T` is taken from `graph` parameter:

```
const std::type_identity_t<T>& root
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ye75M)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. thanks!